# Split parse object from parse.com Android by columns

Tags: android, string, parse-platform, null

I retrieve parse object from parse. It should contain 5 columns: `id`, `number`, `number2`, `createdAt`, `UpdatedAt`. I try to get values of `objectId` (string) and have this code:

```
public static void Parse_go_to_refresh(){

  final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Table");
  pQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
      if (list.size() >= 0) {

        for (ParseObject po : list) {

          Log.i(TAG, "Id number " + po.getString("objectId"));

          list1.add(po.getString("objectId"));
          Log.i(TAG, "Id number (2) - " + list1);

  }}}});
}
```

But every time I get "`Id number null`" and "`Id number (2) - [null, null, ...]`". Id number 2 is increasing from one [null] to [null, null, null, null, ... null (exact number of my objects in parse.com)] with step equivalent to one null. So I guess my app has downloaded all the objects from parse, but I do a wrong way when I try to get objects id from what I've downloaded.

How can i get a necessary column data from parse object that i have downloaded? Because i've done the same trick in ios and it works like this: download all the parse table to device ->  split it as i want. There i dowloaded it to NSMutableArray -> splited it to NSArrays -> got whatever object from each of them.

Comment: have you tried po.getObjectId() ?

Comment: `id, number, number2, createdAt, UpdatedAt`. `values of objectId` there is no `objectId` in your column list. what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: i meant that id is the objectId - my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static void Parse_go_to_refresh(){

   final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Table");
   pQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

   public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
   if (list.size() >= 0) {

      for (ParseObject po : list) {
         // Get object id like this
         Log.i(TAG, "Id number " + po.getObjectId());

         list1.add(po.getObjectId());
         // Get number like this
         Log.i(TAG, "Id number (2) - " + po.getInt("id"));

      }
   }
 }});
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved a problem with Id number - now it returns me the right data. But "Id number (2)" now gives me 0 for all the objects. Can you help with one more little question? How can i get object data for column ("name" for example) for the ObjectId that i need? For example i want to know the name of the third ObjectId (objectId = 3)

Comment: pass your correct column name for id number 2 and if there is no records in that column then it returns 0 by default.For column "name" use like `po.getString("name")`.

Comment: I fixed it. I get all the values for column "name" by calling Log.i(TAG, "Id number " + po.getInt("name")); But now i want to be able to get "name" for object with objectId=3. How and where i am supposed to do it? I expect something like this: int name3 = po.getInt("name")[2];

Comment: Store your name in ArrayList in for loop then wherever you want access from this ArrayList like list.get(3).

Comment: thank a lot for help. But i am new to these things and would really appreciate if you provide me an example of how to store it and then to retrieve whatever value of whatever object. Thank you in advance!